# Thunderbolt 3 (female) to thunderbolt 2 (male) adapter cable?

Tags: macbook-pro

Is there a Thunderbolt 3 (female) to thunderbolt 2 (male) adapter cable?
I'd like to know if I can connect a thunderbolt 3 external SSD drive to a Macbook Pro 2012 with Thunderbolt 1 port.  Wouldn't this get me a faster startup drive than an internal SATA SSD?  I learnt that some of these external drives are faster than SATA SSDs.

Comment: Did you get it?

Comment: I couldn't' find such adapter, but I found this SSD (I'm sure there other SSDs with a female Thunderbolt 3 port).  Then use a Thunderbolt 1 male to Thunderbolt 2 female adapter + a Thunderbolt 2 male to male cable (Apple sells both).  This should work, I connected a 2012 MBPro and a 2017 MBP in target disk mode with this cable combination and it worked fine.